# Parsing retweet profile image

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, uitableview

I'm working on a app that displays a Twitter's user timeline. The `UITableView` contains cells that has the tweet, time and profile icon. But, a retweet still has the user's profile image and not the original poster's image. The JSON file adds a new key called `retweeted_status` that has a key called `user` which has the profile image URL contents. How can I make a conditional statement to find if that `retweeted_status` is there. If not,  then get the image, as the code below does:

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tweetTableView
 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }

dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("image downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSDictionary *tweet =_dataSource[[indexPath row]];
    NSDictionary *tweetSubtitle = _dataSource[[indexPath row]];

    //NSURL *retweetURL = [NSURL URLWithSting: [[tweet objectForKey:@"retweeted_status"] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];


    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[tweet  objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    //Need conditional function to find if retweet

    //NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        cell.textLabel.text = tweet[@"text"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = tweetSubtitle[@"created_at"];


        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
   //NSLog(@"screen name %@", tweetSubtitle[@"screen_name"]);

 return cell;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you -

```
if ([tweet objectForKey:@"retweeted_status"])
{
// the tweet has a retweeted status
}
else
{
// no retweeted status
}
```

am I right? this is what you want?

Comment: Yes,  that is what I am trying to get.

Comment: so whats the problem with the code I wrote? i mean, this is the way to check if an element is there...